# Xui js jquery like live event

Tags: javascript

I am using xui js for a mobile web app. Xui js doesn't support the live event like jquery `$("#selector").live()`. I would like to write some thing at approximates the jquery live.

How does jquery handle event delegation?

Thank you for your time

Mac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just set the event handling on the `document` (*as `live` does*), or even better find a parent of the elements you want to handle and bind to that (*as the `delegate` does*).

Here is a plugin to simulate the `delegate` function of jquery.

```
xui.extend({
    is: function (selector) {
          var matchedNodes = x$(selector), i=0;
          for (i; i<matchedNodes.length; i++)
            if (this[0] == matchedNodes[i]) return true;
          return false;
     },
    delegate: function(selector, event, handler){
        this.on(event, function(evt){
            var elem = evt.target;

            if ( x$(elem).is(selector) ){
                handler.apply(x$(elem), arguments);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**Usage**

```
x$('ul').delegate('li','click', function(){ this.attr('style','color:red'); });
```

This will bind an listener to the `ul` elements, that will handle `click` events initiated by their descendant `li` elements. (*it will change the clicked elements color to red*)

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/vhsPU/

Comment: Thanks for that I tried something very similar is morning www.webpoint-server.com/xui

Answer (score 3):

To expand on Gaby's answer...

I needed to also look to see if the immediate child was clicked. This can be expanded further to have more of a true delegate like we have in jQuery. However, this code sufficed for my needs.

```
xui.extend({
    is: function (selector) {
      var matchedNodes = x$(selector), i=0;
      for (i; i<matchedNodes.length; i++)
        if (this[0] == matchedNodes[i]) return true;
            return false;
    },
    delegate: function(selector, event, handler){
        this.on(event, function(evt){
            var elem = evt.target;

            if ( x$(elem).is(selector) ){
                handler.apply(x$(elem), arguments);
            } else{
                 if ( x$(elem.parentElement).is(selector) ){
                     handler.apply(x$(elem.parentElement), arguments);
                 }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As every event delegation system, it makes usage of the fact that browser events do bubble "bottom up". That means, if we have a structure like

```
<body>
    <div>
        <span>foobar 1</span>
        <span>foobar 2</span>
        <span>foobar 3</span>
    </div>
</body>
```

and somebody clicks on the inner `foobar` span, the browser checks if any event handlers are bound to the span for that click event. If so, execute them. Now the event "bubbles up" to its parent (`div`). Again, the browser checks if any click event handlers are bound to it, if so execute, and so forth up until the `document.documentElement`.

In the above example, we would need to bind three event handlers for every `<span>` element. Knowing the above described concept, we now can just bind one event handler to the `<div>` parent node and check for the `target` within the `event object`. That target is always the original element where the event happened.

There are a couple more things to know. You can stop the propagation of events for instance to explicitly not allow an event to bubble up any further. That can be done by invoking `.stopPropagation()` which is a method from the event object.